# ajax and woocommerce page loaded twice

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce

```
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'admin_menu'), 100 );

public function admin_menu() {
    $page = add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product', __( 'ajaxmain' ), __( 'ajaxmainagain' ), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_csv_product_role', 'manage_woocommerce' ), 'ajaxmain-product', array( $this, 'output' ) );
}

public function output() {
    include( 'ajaxmain.php' );
}
```

when i use the above code:
ajaxmain.php is getting loaded 2 times.
and then ajaxmain.php doesnt work either.
maybe because there are two elements with the same id now.
actually some elements make ajax request while some elements do not make an ajax request.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

the page is not getting loaded twice now.
i had a base class and an inherited class.
and i tried to instantiate both classes and my     `add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'admin_menu'), 100 );` was in the `constructor` of the base class.
hence page was loaded two times.

however the single load of the page is not working with ajax.